How do I return a numpy array in rust using pyo3?
I am doing a python project that needs a bit of a speed boost, so I am making rust do a bit of the heavy lifting. What my project requires is that I can take in a numpy array, convert it to a rust array, apply some function to it, and return it as a numpy array. My only problem right now is specifying the lifetime of the return type (it is giving me the error "missing lifetime specifier
this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the signature does not say whether it is borrowed from py or array" under this bit of code:
-> PyResult<Vec<&str>> 

).
All I really need right now is for that error to be fixed. Here is my full rust code:
use pyo3::wrap_pyfunction;
use numpy::PyArrayDyn;

#[pymodule]
fn dnd_images(py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(get_shape_instructions, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}

#[pyfunction]
fn get_shape_instructions(py: Python, array: &PyArrayDyn<u16>) -> PyResult<Vec<&str>> {
    let array = unsafe { array.as_array() };
    let mut result: Vec<&str>;
    for element in array{
        let s: String = element.to_string();
        result.push(&s);
    }
    
    Ok(result)
}

All I have tried, as I am not very experienced with rust, is mashing things together in different orders and functions with different types according forums, articles, tutorials, and GPT-4.


Your return type is not correct: &str is a borrowed string, and it's borrowed from the local frame, which can't be valid because the corresponding String structures will be destroyed at the end of the function (in fact at the end of each loop iteration). This is an area where Rust is very strict and you're going to have lots of sads if you don't learn about it for real. Unless you have intuition about it from significant experience with low level languages with manual memory management (e.g. C / C++) it is not something which is likely to be natural and intuitive.
In this specific case you could just return a Vec<String> and push the result of the to_string call directly on the output vec.

In PyO3, a rust Vec converts to and from a python list, if you want to return a numpy array the rust-side type has to be some variant of PyArray including PyArrayDyn.


Also you should really 1. read and 2. post the compilation errors. Rust's tend to be quite detailed and provide good informations and even hints.
Complete reproductions are also appreciated, whether on playground / godbolt, or with all the necessary content, so that they're easier to consider and manipulate.
